# Push to github gist failing

Tags: git, github, gist

Trying to push a PNG to my github gist without success.

```
$ git clone https://gist.github.com/6124716.git
$ cd 6124716
$ ls
fed.json     index.html     vermont.json
```

I can then modify index.html and push the change to my github repository. However once I save a png file to the repo I lose the ability to push:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 25.48 KiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Reading about the problem, I've seen suggestions to increase the buffer size:

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But I still get the same error message. Furthermore, vermont.json is much larger than the PNG I am trying to upload.

```
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x   7 mparrilla  staff     238 Aug  2 09:53 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 mparrilla  staff     238 Aug  2 09:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 mparrilla  staff     476 Aug  2 09:56 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 mparrilla  staff    5635 Aug  2 09:52 fed.json
-rw-r--r--   1 mparrilla  staff    3381 Aug  2 09:52 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 mparrilla  staff   25776 Aug  2 09:28 thumbnail.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mparrilla  staff  187388 Aug  2 09:52 vermont.json
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770562/posting-images-to-gists-via-the-http-api) seems to be your problem?

Comment: Yes and no. I've pushed PNG files to gist before, so I know it's possible, not sure about the reported lack of support in the linked answer. At any rate, @donatello's solution worked for me.

Comment: Ah, the lack of support is for the API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is with using HTTPS, but as an alternative you could trying using SSH:

To clone a gist via SSH -

```
git clone git@github.com:6124716.git
```

Comment: Hmm. Worked. Thanks. Anyone have any idea what's going on there?

Comment: As of November 2017 this is still a problem: was unable to push using HTTP, — switched to SSH and it works!